# grid-template-columns CSS displaying vertically and not horizontally

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am a student working on a website. I have the below CSS/HTML script that should be displaying cards in order horizontally, however when I view it on a website its showing up vertically instead.

**Goal:**

```
[pic1] [pic2] [pic3] 
[pic4] [pic5] [pic6]
```

**Current Output:**

```
[pic1]
[pic2]
[pic3]
[...]
[pic6]
```

**Current Code:**
I have only included code that should be relevant to my question, please let me know if I should include additional code for guidance.

```css
.cards {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1000px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: auto;
    gap: 20px;
    font-family: Arial;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
    <div class="card">

        <img src="image.jpg" alt="image" class="card__image">
        <div class="card__content">
            <p2>Image</p2>
        </div>
        <div class="card__info">
            <div>
                <a href="" class="card__link"> BOUNTY</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="cards">
    <div class="card">

        <img src="image2.jpg" alt="image" class="card__image">
        <div class="card__content">
            <p2>Image2</p2>
        </div>
        <div class="card__info">
            <div>
                <a href="" class="card__link"> BOUNTY</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why having many card**s** element with one card inside? either consider one or apply the grid property to an upper container

Comment: you have `cards` twice....hence making 2 grids that have 3 columns...which is showing correctly

Comment: I see my mistake. I have two instances of "cards" instead of nesting additional cards within my class "cards".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would really do that with `display: flex` ... why? because it is easier and not that complex to work with `grid` and give your flex-children a `flex-basis of 30%` to have three children in one row.
Nevertheless, you have `div class="cards"` openend twice. you will probably have this div only once and `div class="card__*"` several times.
grid is more compatible with older versions of browsers, like IE11, but also only with the prefix, but that's just my personal thought.

Comment: flex display has the only problem that if the images are of different sizes they will mess up. In that case you could also use [`display: table-cell` (W3C)](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

Comment: yes, but how we all know, using table tag will not have a responsive behavior compared to the newer solution for it (flex). you'll need media queries to split those table-cells (td) to be responsive (afaik)